# I'll have the television working again soon

Tags: causatives

In Oxford Dictionary, there is explained one of the meanings  of the structure "have sth/sb doing...". The meaning is "to cause sth to be done or happen". Here is the example of the usage:
*I'll have the television working again soon*. I would like to ask what what would happen with the meaning of the sentence when "working" changed into the bare "work".

Comment: In this case, it wouldn't make sense, because a television can't do work. A better example might be, "I'll have the men working again soon," vs. "I'll have the men work again soon."

Comment: But the meaning is after all that I managed that the television works again. I repaired it.

Comment: I will **have it {state}** soon.  bare infinitive "work" is not a state.  *I will have it **finished** soon.*  *I will have it **ready** in a jiffy*. *The comedian had them **laughing**.*  *The final exam had them **sweating** and **cussing**.*  *The broken TV had them **swearing**.*    Consider the difference between past participle and present participle in terms of state.

Comment: So "I'll have my father fix the car" is possible while "I'll have the television work again soon" not.

Comment: There are two uses,  cause someone/something to BE {in a state}.   cause someone/something to DO.   *I will have the taxi take you to the airport.*  The decision is a semantic one. We understand the TV to be broken or working. (state).  *We will have the TV show|showing the video signal from the security camera.*  DISPLAY (act)|DISPLAYING (state)

Comment: Yes, I understand your mentioned difference between state and action.  But what role does "ing-form play in the meaning". "I will have the taxi take you to the airport" vs. "I will have the taxi taking you to the airport". Is it just the aspect?

Comment: The difference is that between BE and DO.  **have the taxi taking**  refers to the taxi's ongoing state;  **have the taxi take** refers to the act it does.

Comment: We will have buses shuttling guests to and from the hotel.  We will have buses shuttle guests to and from the hotel. The version with **shuttling** envisions what will be going on;  the version with **shuttle** refers to how we expect to transport guests.  Activity versus  Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's similar to the difference between: I like to play tennis and I like playing tennis. Anglo grammarians often claim there is no difference. Intuitively we can see there is. (I won't bother with the technical explanation, it would take pages.)

He'll have the television working again soon.
He'll have the car running again soon.

For machines, etc. that would be have to be ing generally. As the ING form implies a working or functioning state of a machine. And just work can't be used here as it would imply that televisions or cars perform tasks. (mathewb pointed this out above.)

But let's look at some other example: Imagine a person breaks her leg.

**|John will have her working again** soon|. [John will cause the person to work again soon due to patience or generosity or some other quality]. Here working means **executing some task(s)**. **The focus is on the activity expressed as a gerund.**

If, however, you say (or write): 
**|John will have him work again soon.|** **The focus is on what John will do.**

This is exactly like:

**Working is fun**. [gerund, that is, a noun]

versus

**Work is fun**. [A noun also] but it is the notion that comes into play, rather than the activity per se]

In general, a gerund form implies the activity and a bare verb noun form implies the notion.

I don't expect many to agree with me, but if you think about these two forms operate in actual sentences, they usually account for the difference in meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But not sure whether I understand your example with John. "John will have her working again soon" vs. "John will have her work again soon". Sorry, for my being a little slow on the uptake but can you tell the context for the usage of both versions in your sentence.

Comment: Have her working again=will cause her to engage in the activity of working due to his efforts. [he could be her husband or even boss]; have her work again soon=will cause  her to work again. Last week, John had her brother work. [cause him to work]. One is notional (the bare verb);the other  emphasizes the activity as an activity.

Answer (score 0):

I can see swapping the participle "working" with the infinitive "to work" with some other changes,

> I'll soon get the television to work again

but there's no change in meaning.

The use of "have it working" feels particularly BrE to me, though.  An American might instead prefer "get it working".